# Google calendar api - add a file attachment

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api, attachment

Using python 3.6, requests==2.22.0

I am using the Google API to create an event: [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

In the documentation I see:

```
attachments[].fileUrl   string  URL link to the attachment.
For adding Google Drive file attachments use the same format as in alternateLink property of the Files resource in the Drive API.

Required when adding an attachment.

writable
```

Can I insert a file attachment not via a link-url? 
Will that require a separate call?

```
data = {
    'summary': 'CALENDAR TESTING',
    'location': 'Some fake location',
    'description': 'This is a test',
    'start': {
        'dateTime': 'some iso datetime',
        'timeZone': 'some tz',
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': 'some iso datetime',
        'timeZone': 'some tz',
    },
}

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{}/events'.format(calendar_id)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

response = requests.post(
    url,
    data=json.dumps(data),
    headers=headers,
)
```

Example of an attachment-generating-payload sent to an already existing event in Office365:

```
data = {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
    "name": "<String, file name>.pdf",
    "contentBytes": <b64 encoded pdf bytes>
}
```

My goal is to attach a PDF file to the event. 
In case I missed a documentation reference please point me to it - otherwise I will appreciate what is necessary to add to the above Google event creation payload to make this happen, or the url + payload schema to attach post-event creation. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Google does not support events attachments that are not store on Drive.
I am evaluating possible workarounds for the issue.