# Is it possible to Add Attachments with a Google Calendar Addon using Alternate runtime

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

I've been trying to Add Attachments with a Google Calendar Addon using alternate runtimes (Not App scripts), but it seem it's either not documented anywhere or it's just impossible to do.

I'm wondering if anyone knows how this can be done returning proper JSON response from an alternate runtime, or is App Scripts the only option for adding attachments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to create Add ons with other runtimes as suggested by their official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/overview).

There is also a [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/alternate-runtimes-quickstart) that you can take a reference on how to create the add-on.

From the Calendar API events creation to add attachment it only supports Drive files. Sample codes in other languages on how to add the Drive files can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/create-events). There is also a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369364/google-calendar-api-add-a-file-attachment) utilizing Python and also wondering about the process of adding attachments.

Edit:

Would be a good idea to request a feature like that or update to the documentation for supported options:

- https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/support

Comment: Thanks for the links but non of them state how to return an Attachment as JSON response when using alternate runtimes, which takes me back to my original question.
I've also reported the issue on the Issue Tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/234759220#comment2 but it looks like it won't be addressed. 
For now I'm going to focus on using Google Scripts instead.

Comment: It might not be a direct issue, more about a missing feature, if that is the case a feature request might be better, suited, I would edit the response adding that reference.